# Spring webinars downloadable?

Tags: spring, download, spring-boot, webinar

Does anyone of know if it is possible to download a Spring webinar afterwards? Could not find any related information to this. Maybe you know if every Spring webinar will be uploaded to the Spring YouTube channel?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgGXSWYM2FpNmY5a1MuomSvvovSWHWoAR) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Webinars, and many other videos, are available at Springs YouTube channel.

https://www.youtube.com/user/SpringSourceDev